# ScrollViewer does not work properly

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I have the following code in `WPF`:

```
<telerikNavigation:RadTileViewItem Header="New Synonyms">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">

            <telerik:RadCartesianChart>
                <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                    <telerik:CategoricalAxis />
                </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                    <telerik:LinearAxis/>
                </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>

                <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>
                    <telerik:BarSeries Name="barSeriesNewSynonyms">
                        <telerik:BarSeries.DataPoints>
                            <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="hello" Value="10" />
                            <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="hi" Value="5" />
                        </telerik:BarSeries.DataPoints>
                    </telerik:BarSeries>
                </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>
            </telerik:RadCartesianChart>


        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</telerikNavigation:RadTileViewItem>
```

and it seems like this:
[image]

The `scrollViewer` does not work. I also have change the above code in a way that the `scrollviewer` was embedded inside the `Grid` but it gave me the same result. How can the scroll embed the entire content in the grid so all of the content can be visible.
I want to use `ScrollViewer` to fit the items inside it. As it can be seen, the `scrollviewer` does not appear and does not work. The following image shows that every thing is embedded without the need of scroll, but the size changes and I need to have scroll bars.
[image]

I have updated the content of the chart by using the following `C#` code:

```
this.barSeriesOldSynonyms.DataPoints.Clear();
foreach (var it in osr.previousMeanings)
    this.barSeriesOldSynonyms.DataPoints.Add(new Telerik.Charting.CategoricalDataPoint() { Category = it.word.ToString(), Value = it.frequency });
```

Comment: can you post code showing how you are updating the DataPoints in the wpf to the ones in your screenshot?

Comment: @tolanj check the updates

Comment: RadCartesianChart seems to have its own scrolling behaviours, look at:
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radchartview/features/behaviors/panzoom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RadCartesianChart seems to have its own scrolling behaviours, look at [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radchartview/features/behaviors/panzoom).
In summary you can set

```
<telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.Behaviors>
   <telerikChart:ChartPanAndZoomBehavior PanMode="Both" />
</telerikChart:RadCartesianChart.Behaviors>
```

to get 2 scrollbars.